# New table or using commas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to learn your suggestions about that:

Using commas for product's categories

[image]

OR Creating a 3rd table.

[image]

Which one is more useful?

Thanks alot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a 3rd table is definitely the better option.

Using comma-delimited values is only going to cause you problems later down the line. It will also make writing SQL queries a lot more complex than they need, and the performance will be costed for this.

Comment: +1 Simple case: create a select that finds all products of a particular category. You will need to parse the string in that column for the substring that you are interested in - can get expensive. Whereas with a separate table, the category values are already expressed individually in rows.

Comment: Or, the even funner case, when a new product has a comma in its name!